# WebStorm inspector throws "Unresolved variable isRequired" for ReactJS PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, react-proptypes

WebStorm (2019.1.3) throws the warning: "Unresolved variable isRequired" for ReactJS (16.8.6) PropTypes. 
How to solve this warning?

[image: WebStorm warning]

```
Settings.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isSettingsOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

React PropTypes has property `isRequired` (https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes).

*prop-types* (^15.7.2) npm package installed into *"dependencies"*.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you install *prop-types* npm package? Can you show the whole React class maybe it can be better to understand.

Comment: does the issue persist after caches invalidation (*File>Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart*)? Also, does installing prop-types typings (`npm i @types/prop-types`) make things any better?

Comment: _prop-types_ (^15.7.2) npm package installed into "dependencies".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but kept running into this and figured I would help others. I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/30#issuecomment-525220994) with a solution that worked for me.

#### Webstorm 2019.2+ (Tested w/ IntelliJ 2019.3)

Follow these steps:

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`
2. Go to `Download..`
3. Search for "prop-types" (I had to scroll down an alphabetical-ordered list)
   [image]
4. Click `Download and Install`
5. Click `Ok`
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

Issue is reported to JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26418#focus=Comments-27-5331128.0-0

NOTE:
It seems that the issue re-appears in **WebStorm 2021.2.2** (Build #WS-212.5284.41, built on September 14, 2021).

[image]

Comment: This would probably be a useful comment to add to the post, but it shouldn't be posted as an answer since it's just reaffirming the original issue, but not offering a solution.

Comment: The solution is to wait for the fix by JetBrains. Every "fix" is a hack as the issue is not with the language or the library, it's with the IDE (which was the question).